# Autodesk forge translate file from private s3 bucket

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-model-derivative, autodesk-bim360

Is there away to translate an item from a private S3 bucket on was.

I have a web app where the client uploads different types of files to AWS s3 bucket. I would like to use the forge model derivative API to translate the model and extract the data without moving the model to the forge bucket.

Answer (score 0):

Not possible must upload to the Forge bucket for translation.

Comment: can I move it to my own bucket after the translation completed ?!

Comment: yes, you can delete the seed file and use only svf for viewing